# sudo passwd command with no-interactive mode

Tags: command-line, virtualbox, password, sudo

**Context:**

I created a Virtual Machine with Packer for Vagrant system into a Ubuntu 14.04 server OS. All runs perfectly but this is a development VM (I'm alone on this) and I want to administer my system easily and quickly.

**Solution:**

I use all the time the root account on my system.
When my OS is built, I run `sudo passwd`
which tells me to type password for the account root.

**Issue:**

I want to add this command to my vagrant build-in process so I don't have to run it manually, but I can't find a solution for launching this in non-interactive mode.

So,. how can I run `sudo passwd` non-interactively?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you are running as root already, no need to use sudo ;)

```
echo "root:your_desired_root_password"|chpasswd
```

Works in scripts as well.

See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/chpasswd.8.html

You can also use expect or other scripts:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236699/script-to-change-password-on-linux-servers-over-ssh

or similar links

Comment: The OP needs to run `sudo passwd` since that is what enables the root account. As I understand it, they are looking for a way to automate the process of running `sudo passwd` on a new install.

Comment: The vagrant process does not allow setting a root password, it has to be set manually post install. I thought the OP did not want to manually enter a password twice.

Comment: I _think_ they want to automate the process of enabling the root account. I don't have an Ubuntu machine handy to test this on, but I was thinking that it should be possible by editing `/etc/shadow` and entering the appropriate password hash. Want to give it a try?

Comment: I do not understand, how is manually editing /etc/shadow in any way easier or automation ? I would set it with passwd or the commands ( gave rather then manually editing. Also all distros have an /etc/passwd so you can edit on any distro.

Comment: Not manually, I was thinking of something like `pass=$(echo PASSWORD | openssl passwd -1 -salt abc "foobar"); "s/root:[^:]*/root:$pass/" /etc/shadow`. I don't know if that would be possible with Vagrant, however, Can you run commands that need root access during system setup? If you can ,that should work.

Comment: All my scripts commands run with a sudo right with vagrant user. I can run apt-get install but this is not root user. When the build is finish if a want to use root login I must run sudo passwd.

Comment: @terdon - if you are running commands, how is your suggestion easier then chpasswd ? and darkomen sudo == root, lol

Comment: Bodhi.zazen, I know nothing about Vagrant, so my suggestion may well be completely idiotic. My idea is that those commands can be scripted (assuming Vagrant can run commands as root) and don't require interaction from the OP. As I understand it, the problem is that @darkomen doesn't want to have to manually type in the password as is required when running `sudo passwd`.

Comment: if I try this : echo "root:toto"|chpasswd I have this return : error of manipulate authentication token. But the same command run perfectly another environment on another computer...

Comment: echo "root:your_desired_root_password"|chpasswd, run correctly into script file for vagrant provisionning but not into vagrant itself it's strange but this resolve my issue. Very thank for all contributing.